# Read in Specific Tabs from Excel into R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation, readxl

I am trying to read a bunch of tabs from an excel file into R. The issue is that I only want some of the tabs, not all of them. When I try to select certain columns, I get an error because the tabs I do not want to read in don't contain the x1:x4 columns I want. My current code is below.

```
file.list <- "C:/Users/xxxx/Documents/file.xlsx"

df.list <- lapply(file.list,function(x) {
  sheets <- excel_sheets(x)
  dfs <- lapply(sheets, function(y) {
    read_excel(x, sheet = y, skip = 5) %>% 
      clean_names() %>% 
      select(x1:x4)
  })
  names(dfs) <- sheets
  dfs 
})[[1]]

list2env(df.list ,.GlobalEnv)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`select` can take helper functions.  Instead of specifying directly, wrap with `any_of`.  According to `?select`

> any_of(): Same as all_of(), except that no error is thrown for names that don't exist.

```
df.list <- lapply(file.list,function(x) {
  sheets <- excel_sheets(x)
  dfs <- lapply(sheets, function(y) {
    read_excel(x, sheet = y, skip = 5) %>% 
      clean_names() %>% 
      select(any_of(stringr::str_c('x', 1:4)))
  })
```

Comment: hmmm, I still get an error using any_of and all_of. Error: object 'x1' not found. Not all the tabs I am reading in have the x1:x4 columns

Comment: @bodega18 try `select(any_of(c('x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4')))`

Comment: @bodega18 the issue was that you are using range helper within another helper.  Instead pass a vector of strings as in the updated

Comment: ah yep it worked once I put the column names in quotes. What if I want to read in x1 and all columns to the right? I tried something like select(any_of(c('x1':length(x)))) but that did not work.

Comment: @bodega18 What if `x1` is not found with that case.  Here, you are assuming that 'x1' would always be present?

Comment: ah you are right. Last question - How could I create a helper column for each object I read in that identifies the tab it is coming from?

Comment: @bodega18 Do you need the column with values from `sheets`, then you can add the  after the `clean_names` i.e. `%>% mutate(sheet = y) %>% select(any_of(stringr::str_c('x', 1:4)), sheet)`